# What is the proper way of finding a woman to marry with?

Tags: practical-islam

I am looking for a general consensus on how to properly meet/find/get introduced to woman to marry with.

Imagine someone who doesn't have a lot of friends, no parents or other family close to him. So he has no men to contact and ask whether he knows any women he could get introduced to do. In fact, is that even allowed? Or for example, there is a father but he can offer little assistance.

Clearly going to a bar should be avoided, approaching random women on the street is a no-go too. So what are the guidelines? Surely God is asked for help and I know rocks which are designated to not move will not move without His command.

Answer (score 2):

It is undoubtedly a commendable thing that you are seeking to get married to a pious lady. It appears from your question that you live in a non-Muslim country.

If you go to a Masjid regularly, you can take some people (preferably in the administration as they would know most of the community) into confidence and state your intention. In my opinion, this would be the best way to proceed with your search.

There are many many websites geared towards Muslims' matrimonial searching. I only have seen their ads and don't have any more experience, but they appear to be a better choice than the methods you described and want to avoid.

May Allah help you in your efforts for this noble cause.